# JavaScript Toggle Mobile Menu, not working

Tags: javascript, slidetoggle

My JavaScript isn't working. I am attempting to toggle the mobile menu. This is the console error message.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBSjb.jpg)

```
const button = document.getElementById('menu-button')
const nav = document.getElementById('menu')

function navToggle() {
button.classList.toggle('open')
nav.classList.toggle('hidden')
document.body.classList.toggle('no-scroll')

}


button.addEventListener('click', navToggle)
```

Comment: button is undefined. Attach all code

Comment: Make sure `const button = document.getElementById('menu-button')` doesn't return null value

Comment: also, question's title and tags contain `slidetoggle` which is never used

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.